# how to differentiate laravel 5.5 auth::routes() as it make the same name route on the frontend and backend

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

web.php

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Web',
], function ($route) {

  $route->get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
  Auth::routes();
});


Route::group([
  'prefix' => 'admin',
  'namespace' => 'Admin',
],function ($route)
{
    Auth::routes();
    $route->get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

php artisan route:list
I got

```
Method   | GET|HEAD  
URI      | login                        
Name     | login                  
Action 
         |App\Http\Controllers\Web\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                  Middleware 
         | web,guest


Method   |GET|HEAD  
URI      | admin/login                  
Name     | login                  
Action 
         |App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm
Middleware
         |web,guest:admin
```

I copy the auth folder to the admin and web folder

```
views/admin/auth/login.blade.php
views/web/auth/login.blade.php
```

the both php have the same form action

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
```

But no matter the url is

```
localhost:8000/login
```

or

```
localhost:8000/admin/login
```

it can show the diffent login.blade.php page
but the {{route('login')}} is always point to the url

```
localhost:8000/admin/login
```

cannnot point to the

```
localhost:8000/login
```

no matter the url is
`localhost:8000/login` or `localhost:8000/admin/login`

how can I differentiate the same  route name on the route link

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you cleared route cache?

`php artisan route:cache`

Do it after each change in routes.

Look at this example:

```
    Route::group([
        'module' => 'Admin',
        'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers',
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        'middleware' => ['web']
    ], function() {


        Route::group([
            'prefix' => 'user'
        ], function() {

            Route::get('/index', [
                'as' => 'get.index-user.index',
                'uses' => 'IndexUserController@getIndex'
            ]);

        });

       Route::group([
            'prefix' => 'admin'
        ], function() {

            Route::get('/index', [
                'as' => 'get.index-admin.index',
                'uses' => 'IndexAdminController@getIndex'
            ]);

        });

    });
```

Comment: After I  use php artisan route:clear  the result is the same
I post two picture to show my question.  
It's the Auth::routes() function to make the same route name. I can write the router path by myself,but it is lost the convenientof auth::routes()  function.

Comment: Then you need to change Auth:routes(). Better solution is to write own login module - then you are free to set routes.